# "flash" when loading remote media with the MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

When loading media (MP4) from a content provider on GoogleTV, I get a "flash" before the video is actually played.  I checked to confirm that there is no redirect, which is known to cause this "flash"  Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to play the video url in main UI thread?Try getting the video url in a separate task by extending Asynctask class and start the video.You may also want to show a progress dialog while the video is loading.

Comment: It is running in a separate thread.  I am also using prepareAsync() rather than just prepare(). Both have the same effect though.